# How does hashset find value to print out with O(1) time complexity?

Tags: time-complexity, hashtable, hashset

I understand that with help of value a certain key is produced and inserted to the table with the corresponding value. When I want to see if a value is in the hashset, it computes the key again, searches for the same key and prints out the value. But doesn't larger amount of keys make it more time-consuming to compare, like O(n) ? I understand that with arrays, it just has to increase the counter until it findes the same index. But with hashsets it can't simply increase the counter , because a key is not simply previous_key+1, like indexes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash table data structures make use of a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) that maps the key to a number of desired size and properties. It also makes use of [Random-access memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory) (RAM) to perform average constant-time lookups.

You know that with a standard array, you can typically access elements with their index in constant-time. This is due to how a computer's memory works in practice. Within the constraints of the hardware, you can store an array as long as you like, but indexed access will happen in constant time. You never have to iterate through your entire RAM memory as long as you know where something is stored.

With hash tables, you essentially map the key to an index, which lets you access the part of memory you stored something at previously.

In practice, there are more things going on (collision handling, buckets etc.), but this is the basic principle. See [HashTable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) on Wikipedia.